# Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have two devise models- Student and Teacher. All of my Rspec tests are passing, which must go through the sign up/sign in process. The thing is, the exact same code works on a friend's computer, however, when I run the rails server on my machine, and try to access the teacher sign in form by going to http://localhost:3000/teachers/sign_in, I get this stack trace in my terminal:

```
ArgumentError in Devise::SessionsController#new
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Here is my full stack trace from the terminal:

Started GET "/teachers/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-04-09 13:39:11 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  devise (3.5.6) lib/devise.rb:464:in `[]'
  devise (3.5.6) lib/devise.rb:464:in `block (2 levels) in configure_warden!'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:34:in `fetch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:212:in `user'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:322:in `_perform_authentication'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:104:in `authenticate'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:114:in `authenticate?'
  devise (3.5.6) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:103:in `require_no_authentication'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:145:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:145:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (45.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (40.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/charlieperson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (90.3ms)
```

The devise sign up/sign in form does show up correctly when I go to http://localhost:3000/students/sign_in but once I click log in I get this error:

ArgumentError in DashboardController#index
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

def index
    @student = current_student
    *@teacher = current_teacher* (It doesn't like this line)
  end

Essentially, it refuses to recognize or let me use the devise helper methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this is not clear enough, please let me know. I searched for an answer for a very long time, tried many proposed solutions, without any luck.

Comment: does your `index` method write in one line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [caused by this line](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.5.6/lib/devise.rb#L464) inside the devise gem, which suggests that `key` is not what devise expects it to be, perhaps there's something in your session that devise is choking on.

Try resetting your session (have your friend do the same on his computer) by deleting your browser cookies for your site.

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot believe that was the issue!!